# Change with the command iptables not reflected in the output of the command netstat

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Scenario: A virtual machine `UU` (abbrev for Ubuntu) is serving a web-page. The web-page is accessible on `CO` (abbrev. for CentOS) which has the Virtual Box on which `UU` is running. However the web-page is not accessible on the rest of LAN. From a randomly selected machine on the LAN I was able to ping `CO` but was not able to pinb `UU`. From `CO` I can ping `UU`.

After referring to a few resources on the web, I think I know the problem (though please feel free to correct me). The output of the comment `netstat -lntu` (**ref:** [get list of open ports](https://superuser.com/questions/529830/get-a-list-of-open-ports-in-linux)) on `UU` includes the line:

```
tcp6    0     0 :::80       :::*     LISTEN
```

but no such line is included in the output when the same command is run on `CO`. Therefore I decided to open `port 80` on `CO`.

To add `port 80` I tried the following on `CO`:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT<br>
sudo iptables save
```

Everything went well. Still after rerunning `netstat -lntu` the output doesn't say that `port 80` has been opened? What is the correct way to open `port 80`? If the aforementioned way is correct, how to verify that command has worked?

Comment: Allowing a port through iptables is different from having a process opening that port (listening on it) for connections. But I'm not sure that's your actual problem -- having CO answer http requests doesn't sound like your goal.

Comment: Here's the summary of my problem. The webpage on `UU` is accessible on `CO`. However it is not accessible on the rest of the LAN. How to tell `CO` to allow traffic to and from `UU` from the rest of the lan? (please ref. OP for the abbreviations).

Answer (score 0):

If you can access `UU` Webpage from `CO`and not from another computer on the LAN means that your `UU` Virtual Machine is probably in NAT mode.

In order to make your `UU` VM accessible from the rest of the LAN you need to configure the VM network in Bridge Mode,

This will allow `UU` to directly comunicate with the other nodes instead of using `CO` as intermediate.